# How can I set an activity to a button click variable that is only assigned via TapBarMenu with String as web and an image item as ImageId?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am new to Android development and I have been looking through Q's/Documentation but unable to find direction on what my end game is.

I am building what could be described as a 'content aggregator' and at current I am struggling to see how I can set an activity that proceeds a click on each position to instigate either an Instagram profile mWebView or an API call. Currently my InstagramList.java is as follows -

```
public class InstagramList extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "Kyary Pamyu Pamyu",
            "Tokyo Girls' Style",
            "Haruka Nakagawa",
            "Nemu Yumemi",
            "Moga Mogami",
            "Ayane Fujisaki",
            "Koda Kumi",
            "Atsuko Maeda",
            "Tomomi Itano",
            "Haruna Kojima",
            "Utada Hikaru",
            "Shibasaki Ko",
            "Taeyon",
            "Tiffany",
            "Jessica",
            "Sooyoung",
            "Sunny",
            "Laboum",
            "YeEun",
            "Yubin",
            "Hyelim"
    };
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.kyary,
            R.drawable.tgs,
            R.drawable.haruka,
            R.drawable.nemu,
            R.drawable.moga,
            R.drawable.ayane,
            R.drawable.koda,
            R.drawable.atsuko,
            R.drawable.tomomi,
            R.drawable.haruna,
            R.drawable.utada,
            R.drawable.shibasaki,
            R.drawable.taeyon,
            R.drawable.tiffany,
            R.drawable.jessica,
            R.drawable.sooyoung,
            R.drawable.sunny,
            R.drawable.laboum,
            R.drawable.yeeun,
            R.drawable.yubin,
            R.drawable.hyelim
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.instagram_main);

        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(InstagramList.this, web, imageId);
    }
}
```

The xml for this is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Any pointers on how best to either modify this to allow better control of these variables or on a possible solution would be greatly received. Apologies if this has been asked in a similar vein before.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking. Are you just trying to find out how you can retrieve which item was clicked in your list? Then start another `Activity` based on that? Also, show your `CustomList` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that you are using two arrays. In place of this you can create a class with one member as string (web) and other as int (imageId). In addition to this you can add one variable for possible action as you mention there can be different actions. In adapter you can add tag on view and click listener so you can perform different actions on different item click.
Hope I understand your problem correctly. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply on this. I see what you mean there but would it be possible to have an example of the stratification?

Comment: Ex:- in onBindViewHolder:- buttonEnterPrice.setTag(position); buttonEnterPrice.setOnClickListener(onClickHandler);   private class OnClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
    {Object objectTag = view.getTag();
        Integer position;

        if (objectTag != null)
        {
            position = (Integer) objectTag;
  ...
  ...

        }}

Comment: And using that position retrieve object from data list and then perform action in onClick method accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/faranjit/listview-itemclick-demo). In `onItemClick` method in `MainActivity` do what you want.