# how to use intent and bundles for custom list view

Tags: java, android, listview

I am new to android application development.. I am trying to create new activity for button click inside a custom list view..(i.e) I want to add on Click event for buttons used in item of List view. How can I give on Click event for buttons in List Item. I am trying to use intent and bundles to pass data for two different activities. but If I use intent then it is not working properly for me.. anyone please help me to solve this..

Comment: add some code first, how you are trying to add onClick event to items

Comment: You have two questions, For list view use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894234/how-can-i-set-an-activity-to-a-button-click-variable-that-is-only-assigned-via-t/38895051#38895051

Comment: here is the code :  https://jsfiddle.net/mawy0tLa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not post any code, I will try my best to give an answer based on your question. You want button click events inside `ListView` items. Simply get the id using `findViewById()` for the button inside the `getView()` method of the `ListView` and add an `onClickListener` on that button. Start the new activity inside this onClick event.

**Edit:**
based on your comments change the line :

```
intent.putExtra("data",tvmername.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
```

to this:

```
intent.putExtra("data",holder.tvmername.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
```

Code for ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<CarrotModel> carrotModelList;
    private int resource;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<CarrotModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        carrotModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

            holder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
           holder.tvmername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMerName);
            holder.tvDealDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDealDesc);
            holder.tvOfftoDis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOftoDis);
            holder.tvmeradd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvmeradd);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        final ProgressBar progressBar;


        progressBar=(ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(carrotModelList.get(position).getImageURL(), holder.ivIcon, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        holder.tvDiscount.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getDiscount() + "% OFF");
        holder.tvmername.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getMerchantName());
        holder.tvDealDesc.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getDealDescription());
        holder.tvOfftoDis.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getOffersToDisplay());
        holder.tvmeradd.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getMerchantAddress());

        Button Button1= (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data",holder.tvmername.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
       private ImageView ivIcon;
        private TextView tvDiscount;
        private   TextView tvmername;
        private TextView tvDealDesc;
        private TextView tvOfftoDis;
        private  TextView tvmeradd;

    }


}
```

Comment: I tried that method but still it not working for me.. here is the code :  https://jsfiddle.net/mawy0tLa/

Comment: is this code running ok or are you getting any errors(Other than that button click)?

Comment: code is running properly.. when button was clicked it shows error

Comment: 08-24 19:03:12.466 3833-3833/com.carrotmonk.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.carrotmonk.myapplication, PID: 3833
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: I think you are getting this error in your SecondActivity.java class , there must be some 'TextView' there where you are setting the data passed as intent. Check to see if that 'TextView' is properly initialized/or may be you are not getting the id correctly. Let me know if your problem is solved

Comment: I think I declared properly.. here is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/mawy0tLa/1/

Comment: row.xml.. https://jsfiddle.net/mawy0tLa/2/                row1.xml: https://jsfiddle.net/mawy0tLa/3/

Comment: sry.. actually where i have to find it

Comment: I have posted the whole code, for your MovieAdapter class

Comment: if i want to come back to my list page means how to close the second activity

Comment: call finish() on you back pressed or in onOptionsItemSelected() method for the id android.R.id.home.

Comment: I am having one more question... actually I am using this list view in android studio tabbed action bar layout.. so by default it is having sliding tab layout fragment.. but I am using my json parser and adapter in mainactivity itself..  When I click on first tab my list view should be shown.. so that im trying to keep json parser method at first tab fragment but it not working it is showing error as make jsontask as static.. if do that in adapter, getapplication() throwing error as make jsontask as not static.. plzz help me to solve it

Comment: if it is text means I can use like this..intent.putExtra("data",holder.tvmername.getText().toString()); instead of text if i want to pass ImageView means then what I have to use

Answer (score 0):

Just do below changes.

```
  Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data",holder.tvmername.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
```

If still you got NullPointerException then send resource file.

Comment: if it is text means I can use like this..intent.putExtra("data",holder.tvmername.getText().toString()); instead of text if i want to pass ImageView means then what I have to use